# Understanding the solution for asymptotic density and $\sigma$-field

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, proof-explanation

The problem that I am looking at is:

> A set $A \subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is said to have asymptotic density $\theta$ if
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}|A \cap \{ 1,2, \ldots, n \}|/n = \theta.
> $$
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of sets for which the asymptotic density exists. Is $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma$-filed? a field?

The solution that I am looking at is:
[image]

I do not understand the computation here. For example for item (1), my understanding is the following: $|(A \cap B) \cap \{ 1, 2, \ldots, 2^{2m} \}| = \sum_{k = 1} ^m \frac{1}{2}|I_{2k - 1}|$ because it is essentially all of the even numbers in the interval $\bigcup_{k = 0} ^\infty I_{2k + 1} \cap \{ 1, 2, \ldots, 2^{2m} \}$. Given that these intervals are disjoint, we have the summation. However, **the second equality** in the chain of equations seems like wrong to me as my computation gives the following:
$$
\sum_{k = 1} ^m \frac{1}{2}|I_{2k - 1}| = \sum_{k = 1} ^m 2^{2k - 3} \not= 1 + \sum_{k = 2} ^m 2^{2k - 3}.
$$
What am I not seeing here?

Comment: I think that you are right in the details. However, this doesn't change the conclusion when you take the limit as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Did you mean the limit is still $\frac{1}{6}$? It doesn't appear that I get this limit if I change the numerator?

Comment: Yes because everything is divided by $2^{2m}$ which goes to $\infty $ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I believe I got $\frac{1}{24}$ for the first limit and $\frac{1}{12}$ for the second one. Everything got divided by two. The conclusion that $A \cap B \not\in \mathcal{A}$ still holds though.